# Unable to start Gwibber

Tags: 11.10, gwibber

When I start Gwibber, I get the following errors:

```
(gwibber:2176): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_property: object class `GwibberAccount' has no property named `uid'
** (gwibber:2176): DEBUG: streams.vala:199: Getting non-transient model
** (gwibber:2176): DEBUG: streams.vala:201: stream_model from resources has 338 rows

(gwibber:2176): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_radio_button_set_group: assertion `!g_slist_find (group, radio_button)' failed

(gwibber:2176): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class `TabWidgetsButton' has no property named `draw-indicator'

(gwibber:2176): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(gwibber:2176): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_property: object class `GwibberAccount' has no property named `uid'

(gwibber:2176): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_radio_button_set_group: assertion `!g_slist_find (group, radio_button)' failed
** (gwibber:2176): DEBUG: tab-bar-widgets.vala:302: facebook not supported

(gwibber:2176): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_property: object class `GwibberAccount' has no property named `uid'
**
Pango:ERROR:/build/buildd/pango1.0-1.29.4/./pango/pango-layout.c:3630:process_line: assertion failed: (result == BREAK_SOME_FIT || result == BREAK_EMPTY_FIT)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: It is possible you found a [bug that should be reported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Has Gwibber worked for you on this install before, or did it stop working after you made some sort of system change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK now. I installed `pango-graphite` and everything fine.

Comment: You should *accept this answer*, so it's clear to other people searching that this question has been solved and what the solution is. (You were unable to do so when you first posted it, because you have to wait 2 days between posting your own answer to your question and accepting it.)